# marking end of file while redirecting to a file in a non-interactive bash script using cat

Tags: bash, echo, eof, cat

I'm trying to redirect a multi-line string to a file. The string contains special chars like **quota** and looks like this:

```
import "this"
import "that"
main() {
    println("some text here");
}
```

I can use `echo` such as:

```
echo "import \"this\"
import \"that\"
main() {
    println(\"some text here\");
}" > myfile.txt
```

The problem with this approach is that I need to escape all **quota** chars. I thought about using `cat` to eliminate the need for escaping. It works well in interactive shells so that I can type `cat > myfile.txt` and then write my string without escaping and then mark the end of file with `<control>d`.

How can I mark `EOF` in the script without the actual key sequence `<control>d`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a 'here document':

```
cat <<'EOF' > myfile.txt
import "this"
import "that"
main() {
    println("some text here");
}
EOF
```

The quotes around the initial 'EOF' mean "do not expand any shell variables (etc) in the here document".